# How to bind ngui events in StrangeIoC in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, inversion-of-control, ngui

I have some problem with binding ngui events in the StrangeIoC framework.

This is an unityGUI sample:

```
public class TestView : View
{
    private readonly Rect buttonRect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 50);
    public Signal buttonClicked = new Signal();

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUI.Button(buttonRect, "Test"))
        {
            buttonClicked.Dispatch();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the NGUI version:

```
public class NGUIView : View
{
    public UIButton Button;
    public Signal buttonClicked = new Signal();


    private void Start()
    {
        if (Button != null)
        {
            EventDelegate.Add(Button.onClick, buttonClicked.Dispatch);
        }
    }
}
```

In the NGUI version, the the buttonClicked is never dispatched. I noticed in the scene the Notify property on that button has an empty value.

This one works, but the buttonClicked is triggered several times :(

```
public class NGUIView : View
{
    public UIButton Button;
    public Signal buttonClicked = new Signal();


    void Update()
    {
        if (Button.state == UIButtonColor.State.Pressed)
        {
            buttonClicked.Dispatch();
        }
    }
}
```

Could you kindly tell me how do you handle this NGUI-StrangeIoC situation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out. Add the delegate in `Awake` instead of `Start`.

Now here's the perfect solution(not sure enough):

```
public class TestView : View
{
    private readonly Rect buttonRect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 50);
    public UIButton Button;
    public Signal buttonClicked = new Signal();

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUI.Button(buttonRect, "Test"))
        {
            buttonClicked.Dispatch();
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        EventDelegate.Add(Button.onClick, buttonClicked.Dispatch);
    }
}
```